# impossible to render a video

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I use blender as a video editor.
I did create/ cup my movie but when I want to render it, I see the render window, the frame counter that increment but no image.
When finished, I check the result and I have a fully black movie that last the timing of my editing.

I did set the parameters to beginning frame and end frame, did choose FFmpeg video with encoder set on MPEG4 and H.264.
I did refresh my codec in my computer : no change....

I'm lost and don't know what to do.
I did open an 3D model I did and try to render an image of it = same result. No image.

---

I don't know how to check and or change the video codec output settings.

In blender, my settings are

[image]

Comment: ...and my rendering engine is set to "Eevee"

Comment: This can often be caused, in my experience at least, by using incorrect/incompatible settings in your video codec output. I'd suggest reviewing those and/or sticking to presets if that helps, but I can't say much without seeing what settings you're using. May help to edit your post with some screenshots.